# C# Get biggest number from a field in a list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a list with this structure:

```
public class Amendment{
    public string name
    public string groupnumber
    public string edition
    public string destination
}
```

The data is as follows

```
var amendmentOne = new Amendment{
    name = "Apple",
    groupnumber = "A12345",
    edition = "A55600E01"
    phonenumber = "2232132123"
}
var amendmentTwo = new Amendment{
    name = "Apple",
    groupnumber = "AG2222",
    edition = "A55600E02"
    phonenumber = "2232132123"
}
var amendmentThree = new Amendment{
    name = "Apple",
    groupnumber = "AG55555",
    edition = "A55600E03"
    phonenumber = "2232132123"
}
```

Is it possible to somehow get the list item with edition number A55600E03 from the list when I loop through it? The edition numbers are all the same except for the last few characters as they will always be E[number]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as easy as

```
var result = List.Orderby(x => edition).Last();
```

**Example**

```
var list = new List<Amendment>{amendmentThree, amendmentOne, amendmentTwo};
var result = list.OrderBy(x => x.edition).Last();
Console.WriteLine(result.edition);
```

**Output**

```
A55600E03
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5tH0ja)